# Adding Asp Net Core Web API Project to MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a solution with 4 layers which its names; Api,Entities,DataAccess and Services. Now I want to add MVC project to my solution to see my datas simple web interface.(I am planning learn Html and Razor).

Api layer is ASPNet Core WebAPI project(with api controllers and CRUD processes) and the others are .Net classlibs. How can I add MVC project for views and how can I use my api from this MVC project?

Comment: Can you add the web api project to your MVC solution?

Comment: I added it via Add Reference.

Comment: You can simply add another MVC project on your solution, then try to call `Web API` from  `MVC`  project like a client side project. Feel free to let me know if you require further asistance.

Comment: I added MVC project to my solution and I will use HTTP Client  to reach my api methods. But  how can I run or debtug multiple projects(api and mvc) on vscode?

Answer (score 4):

1. Right Click on the solution in VS2019 and add **project** > Add **Asp.net core web app**. Select the right framework version, authorization if you want to use it later on.
2. To run multiple projects to gather on VS2019.

Right-click **Solution** > **Set Startup Projects** > **Choose multiple projects** > Choose your API and MVC project as the start.

Make Sure the API project is on top to start it first before the MVC project.
[image]
[image]

3. In the MVC project you need to consume your `API endpoints`, by adding `HttpClient` or `HttpClientFactory` ( I recommend HttpClientFactory, google its advantages).